# Adding mediation degrades whole model

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan

**Updated to a more straightforward question**

Upfront: Every time one adds a mediation term, should the model fit be expected to degrade?

In more practical terms, using lavaan:

```
semModelMIMIC <- '
g =~ fas + dd

g ~ c*escol1 + b*lh_lateralorbitofrontal_area 

lh_lateralorbitofrontal_area ~ a*escol1

ab := a*b

totalaz := c+(a*b)
'
```

And it runs not w/o warning:

```
fitInter <- sem(semModelMIMIC, data = semWellCases, estimator = "ML", missing = "default")
Warning message:
In lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, group.label = group.label,  :
  lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate
```

The fit indices look like:

```
> fitmeasures(fitInter, c("df", "rmsea", "rmsea.ci.lower", "rmsea.ci.upper", "cfi", "aic", "chisq", "pvalue"))
            df          rmsea rmsea.ci.lower rmsea.ci.upper            cfi            aic          chisq 
         1.000          0.000          0.000          0.195          1.000       3472.330          0.152 
        pvalue 
         0.696
```

Above I renamed the created terms in order to simplify. The type of relation I am envisioning looks like the following path (sorry for the blue lines in the background, and note the labels a, b and c; they match the above mediation terms):

[image: Description]

If I add one more mediation term, like in the following syntax:

```
semModelMIMIC <- '
g =~ fas + dd

g ~ u*escol1 + z*lh_lateralorbitofrontal_area 
+ y*lh_medialorbitofrontal_area 

lh_lateralorbitofrontal_area ~ a*escol1
lh_medialorbitofrontal_area ~ b*escol1 

az := a*z
by := b*y


totalaz := u+(a*z)
totalby := u+(b*y)
'
```

The fit indices changes with degradation of chi-square:

```
fitInter <- sem(semModelMIMIC, data = semWellCases, estimator = "ML", missing = "default")
Warning message:
In lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, group.label = group.label,  :
  lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate
> fitmeasures(fitInter, c("df", "rmsea", "rmsea.ci.lower", "rmsea.ci.upper", "cfi", "aic", "chisq", "pvalue"))
            df          rmsea rmsea.ci.lower rmsea.ci.upper            cfi            aic          chisq 
         6.000          0.334          0.267          0.404          0.376       6198.584         72.775 
        pvalue 
         0.000
```

**However, as per suggestion, transformation of the variables with a simple division by /1000 helped improve the overall fit.** What I did was to detect if the variance was too large or too narrow using varTable().

I then transformed the relevant variables:

```
semWellCases$fas <- semWellCases$fas/1000
semWellCases$di <- semWellCases$di/1000
semWellCases$lh_supramarginal_area <- semWellCases$lh_supramarginal_area/1000
semWellCases$escol1 <- semWellCases$escol1/1000
```

varTable() now looks like:

```
varTable(fitInter)
                   name idx nobs    type exo user  mean   var nlev lnam
1                   fas 150  102 numeric   0    0 0.024 0.000    0     
2                    di 152  102 numeric   0    0 0.005 0.000    0     
3 lh_supramarginal_area 423  121 numeric   0    0 3.983 0.493    0     
4                escol1  63  121 numeric   1    0 0.008 0.000    0
```

Running the **first** simpler model now gives me:

```
fitmeasures(fitInter, c("df", "rmsea", "rmsea.ci.lower", "rmsea.ci.upper", "cfi", "aic", "chisq", "pvalue"))
            df          rmsea rmsea.ci.lower rmsea.ci.upper            cfi            aic          chisq         pvalue 
         1.000          0.032          0.000          0.269          0.997      -1955.286          1.100          0.294
```

Which solves my main question about the degradation of the fit. Now, the remaining question is: **Is it usable, since there is a single degree of freedom?**

Comment: What do you mean by the "last correlations". Your model is complex, and I'm having trouble understanding it. I've simplified it a bit, but shorter variable names would make life easier, as would a path diagram.

Comment: You go from 14 to 35 degrees of freedom. Is that would you expect?

Comment: Final point: Your standardized estimates are often very, very close to 1.00. That's often a sign of a problem. And I don't like those std.lv values either.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, simplified the question as per your request. My doubt is about adding interaction terms and the resulting changes in model fit.

Comment: I don't think you mean interaction by mediation (do you?) That's a moderation.

Comment: Take note of this warning:   lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate. It's worth multiplying (or dividing) some of your variables by a constant to be sure that this isn't the source of your worries. I usually aim for the variances to be within an order of magnitude of one another, but perhaps I'm over-cautious.

Comment: I did refer to mediation as an interaction. My mistake. That means I should reserve the term interaction to refer to moderation. Thanks for the correction. So you are suggesting I run some type of transformation to the variables?

Comment: Yes, take a look at your variances (use: apply(semWellCases, 2, var). If values have a very large variance divide by 1000. If they have a very small variance multiple by 1000. (I like to aim for all variances to be between 1 and 10).

Comment: And yes, interaction = moderation, not mediation. (see http://www.public.asu.edu/~davidpm/classes/psy536/Baron.pdf )

Comment: apply is not working in my case, running that way would give me NAs in all variables corresponding to brain areas and a warning of 37 errors (the number of volumetric areas). Further running warning() gives me errors similar to 30: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion. However, inspection of the variables values shows that they seem as expected.

Comment: Jeremy that was useful! The command did not worked as you suggested, but I used varTable instead and later transformed the variable with a /1000. That improved the rmsea and the cfi. Thanks! Now the question about the df remains. the resulting report gives me a df of one. Should I ditch it? Or is it useful in any way?

Comment: Edited to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: Now I think you should go back to your original more complex model, and see if you have the same problem that you had before.

Comment: Also, I'm confused why that transformation seemed to change your df.

Comment: I forgot about the missing data with the var function. You can use: apply(semWellCases, 2, na.rm=TRUE, var). (Or you can find a different solution, as you did).

Comment: The transformation did not change the df, the df of one is for the simpler model. Now, the model with a single mediation still has good fit, but one df and adding more mediations to the model degrades the fit. I am ok to work with one mediation per model, but my concern is that a df of 1 would make the model unusable...

Comment: Ah, I got it. Perhaps add one mediator at a time, to see where the problem is?